# Add to order notes a custom checkout field generated by plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

As per the title I would need to display custom fields in the notes of woocommerce orders so that they are also visible from the woocommerce mobile app.

I should do this operation on two different sites, in one the custom field "n_table" is generated by the plugin "checkout field editor", while in another site I should display two custom fields generated by a plugin that allows to choose the day and time for the pickup of the goods.

I tried the following code (found and adapted from stockoverflow):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'add_n_tavolo' );

function add_n_tavolo( $order_id ) {

//because I already have the ID from the hook I am using.
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// The text for the note
    $n_tavolo   = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'n_tavolo', true );


    $note = "Numero Tavolo:$n_tavolo";

// Add the note
    $order->add_order_note( $note );

// Save the data
    $order->save();
}
```

Only the header "table number:" is added in the order notes but the value assigned to the field by the user is not imported, I tried to turn it into either a text type field or a numeric field but no value is imported.

Can someone help me, I realize that the question is quite trivial but I cannot find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the custom data exists at that point?

Comment: well, I supposed that but I'm not sure... I mean, that variable is filled when I press the checkout button like other checkout fields I think, or am I wrong?

Comment: I would double check the key as well. Are you able to share how you are adding or what you are using to add the custom field? Trying to replicate it.

Comment: I've tested using a number of hooks and I can only guess that the data at this point isn't getting saved or the key is incorrect. Specifically using the order key which would only get generated after it is created.

Double check the order meta and make sure that it exists and isn't empty.

Comment: I think you are right, but I can't figure out what hook I have to use to capture the content of that field

Comment: Are you able to link to the site/provide the code for that metadata you are trying to add? There are a few ways it could get added. If its part of the checkout form it would need to get passed with the post data and saved/updated to get added to the order.